# C# barcode read put it into textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, barcode, barcode-scanner

How can I scan a barcode and put it into a textbox?

I know that a barcode reader works as a standard keyboard.

I have a barcode scanner. I have created 5 barcodes (representing the text "box_1", "box_2", ..., "box_5").

When I scan a barcode and put it into notepad it works, i.e. if I scan the barcode "box_1" it puts the text "box_1" into notepad, and so on for the other barcodes.

But when I scan into a textbox it does not work.

If I scan the barcode "box_1" it puts "box_1" into the textbox, but if I scan "box_5" it still puts "box_1" into the textbox.  Whichever barcode I scan, the textbox gets "box_1".

Comment: Please post your code, otherwise we have no idea what you might be doing wrong

Comment: Thanks you Bo Persson for editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The barcode scanner will put the value in whatever TextBox has focus.  Typically a barcode scanner will end the `Enter` key after the value of the barcode.  You could use this to advance to the next TextBox

Is there something different about each barcode that identifies which TextBox the value should be in?  If that is the case, I would recommend having one TextBox which serves as the entry TextBox.  Once entry is complete (you can tell this by looking for the `Enter`), inspect the value and move it to the correct TextBox.

Comment: Thanks you for Responding, i have create more than 1 textbox. each textbox has memorize the value (as if they have cache).

Comment: i got it....i have to clear the cache the navigator(Firefox) everytime after scanner...it is not imposible